# Canvas - How to do background image moving

Tags: javascript

I want background image to keep moving from left to right.
Any idea how can I do that ? I tried to use code from stackoverflow, didnt work, I tried to google, didnt work.
This is my code. There is nothing about the moving background I am just placing it here because it might help. I´d like to know why any code never worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir='ltr'>
    <head>
        <title>Temponary Rush</title>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/classes.js'></script>
        <style>
        body {
            background-color: #232B2B;
            background-image:url('../web/css/cave-background.png');
            background-position:top;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            color:#FFFFFF; 
        }
        #container{
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            display: -webkit-flex; 
            -webkit-justify-content: space-around; 
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;

        }
        #container > div {
            background: #5F85DB;
            padding: 5px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            border:5px inset #DC3D24;
            background-color:#232B2B;
        }
        #container > .advert {
            width:200px;
        }
        canvas {
            background-image:url('imgs/backgrounds/cave-bcg.png');
            background-position:center;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='left' class='advert'>
                levá strana
            </div>
            <div id='center'>
                <canvas id="ctx" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
                <script type='text/javascript'>  

                    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
                    ctx.font = '30px Arial';
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

                    var player = {
                        x: 10,
                        y: 549,
                        spdX: 1,
                        spdY: 51,
                        width:50,
                        height:50
                    };

                    var obstacles = [

                    ];

                    var allowedJump = true;
                    document.onkeydown = function(event){
                        if (event.keyCode === 32 && allowedJump) {
                            for(i; i<10;i++){
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    player.y-= player.spdY/10;   
                                },60);
                            }
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                allowedJump = true;
                                player.y+=player.spdY;
                            },600);
                        };
                        allowedJump = false; 
                    };

                    setInterval(update,10);
                    function update(){
                        ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,600,45);   
                        ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
                        player.x += player.spdX;
                        for(i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++) {
                            ctx.fillRect(obstacles[i][0], obstacles[i][1], obstacles[i][2], obstacles[i][3]);
                            var is_colliding = collision.testCollision(player,obstacles[i][0], obstacles[i][1],obstacles[i][2],obstacles[i][3]);
                            if(is_colliding) {
                                afterImpact.stun(2,player);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            <div id='right' class='advert'>
                pravá strana
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have the website on xampp server for now, later I will go to node.js server.
this is my file tree.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  please remove this code from body
body {
        background-color: #232B2B;
        background-image:url('../web/css/cave-background.png');
        background-position:top;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        color:#FFFFFF;            
    }
```

you can set  the following div code inside the body tag

```
   div{
        background-color: #232B2B;
        background-image:url('../web/css/cave-background.png');
        background-position:top;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;

       }
```

Comment: If I do that what it helps me ?My background color will disapear

Comment: body tag background  is fixed so we can not modify, the alternative for this you have to set div as per the body size and set the div using css accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I did modify my code, but main question is how to do that moving background

Comment: please refer this code and modify accordingly..
   div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition:2s;
    -webkit-transition:2s;
    -moz-transition:2s;
    position:absolute;
    right:calc(100% - 100px);
 }
  div:hover {
    right:0;
  }